# Non-DB backed related objects in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 5 (code first method), and would like to have one of my Entities that is stored in my DB (and is exposed in my `DbContext` with an `DbSet<>` property) have a related object that is NOT stored in the DB.

Below is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
// Stored in DB
public class RecordedMeasure
{
    [Required]
    public int RecordedMeasureID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string MeasureName { get; set; }

    // Navigation Property...
    // Go find the Measure by the MeasureName (which IS persisted to the DB)
    public Measure Measure { get; set;}

    // Additional properties removed for brevity....
}

// NOT Stored in DB
public class Measure{

    public string MeasureName { get; set;}
   
    // Additional properties removed for brevity....
}

// Allows registration and holds a static collection of all "Measures"
// that are known at runtime
public class MeasureRegistration{

    // Allow access to all measures stored
    public static List<Measure> Measures { get; set; }

    // Register a measure
    public static void Register(Measure measure) { 
        // Code removed for brevity...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to expose my `MeasureRegistration.Measures` collection as something that the Entity Framework can work with like it would a typical DbSet?

Thanks!

## Update / Further Clarification

I am aware how to prevent the property from being Mapped to the database however, I am not aware of how to get EF to actually have a "Repository" or collection (like a `DbSet<>`) of NON DB-BACKED models that it can use to fulfill relationships between a DB-backed model and a non DB-backed model.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fulfill relationships"

Comment: Something along the lines of: `modelContext.RecordedMeasures.FirstOrDefault().Measure` and have EF understand how to fulfill that `Measure` property of my `RecordedMeasure`. I realize that this wouldn't be "Automatic" and I would need to build logic into my design that allows for my collection of `Measure`s to be queried against and joined based on my own logic. EF does this through mappings such as `this.HasProperty(o => o.Measure).WithMany(o => o.Measures).HasForiegnKey(o => o.MeasureName);` however... this type of mapping would attempt to hit the DB... `Measure`s aren't stored there

Comment: Basically, I'd like to have a different store backing `Measure`s (my app layer being that store through a Collection or IQueryable or whatever would be necessary) to allow it to be used via EF to Resolve my relationship. This may not even be a feature that is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just add a new property to the context that gives you an IEnumerable and put logic in the getter for retrieving it?

In your Context:

```
public IEnumerable<Measure> Measures { get { return MeasureRegistration.Measures; } }
```

In your entity:

```
[NotMapped]
public Measure Measure 
{ 
    get { return MeasureRegistration.Measures
                .FirstOrDefault(m => m.MeasureName == this.MeasureName; }
    set { this.MeasureName == value.MeasureName;}
}
```

From the question I gather you would like someway to for EF to hook this up for you in which case I think you are out of luck. I'm not sure what advantage that would have either on wiring it up yourself unless you have a bunch of entities referencing Measure.

Comment: Yes I could, unfortunately reading my question now (a year later) I would have answered the same as you did. For some reason (that I cannot recall), that simple solution wasn't what I needed at the time however, for the sake of providing an answer for future visitors, I believe yours fits the question best and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using the `[NotMapped]` Annotation, you can achieve this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx

"*Denotes that a property or class should be excluded from database mapping.*"

Comment: Thanks @cheedep, however this is not quite the answer I was seeking. I have explained further as I think I may not have been clear in my original post.